# Show and update a dialog from AsyncTask that is on a separate file

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an activity with buttons on it. One of the buttons when clicked calls a static method from another class. This method then calls a series of AsyncTasks that are daisy-chained. It is like in the OnPostExecute of the first task, I will call a new AsyncTask, then in the OnPostExecute of the second AsyncTask, I again will call a new AsyncTask. This goes on for about 15 levels. I need to show a progress dialog while these tasks are running and show the appropriate status (percentage). I did this by creating a new ProgressDialog on the OnPreExecute of the first AsyncTask. My problem is when the device is rotated or when it goes to sleep, then the ProgressDialog disappears and an exception is raised when I call dismiss() from the final OnPostExecute.

Here's my code (toned down to 2 levels of Asynctasks)

Activity:

```
private class OnButtonMenuClick implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.textViewDownload:
            downloadReferenceFiles();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewProductNotes:
            showProductNotes();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewCustomerNotes:
            showCustomerNotes();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewAdjustOrders:
            orderAdjustments();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewUploadOrders:
            uploadDataToServer();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewToolsReconciliationIcon:
            cashCount();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewToolsExpensesIcon:
            expensesEntry();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewSalesSummaryIcon:
            showSalesSummary();
            break;              

        case R.id.textViewInventoryIcon:
            showInventory();
            break;

        case R.id.textViewInventoryByVolumeIcon:
            showInventoryByVolume();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void downloadReferenceFiles() {      
    ReferenceFilesDownloader.downloadData(ToolsActivity.this, true);
}
```

Reference files downloader class (separate file)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReferenceFilesDownloader {

private static ProgressDialog progress;
private static Context context;
private static boolean includeInventory;

public static void downloadData(Context ctx) {      
    context = ctx;
    includeInventory = false;   
    new AsyncCheckServerDate().execute();       
}

public static void setContext(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
}

public static void downloadData(Context ctx, boolean inventory) {
    context = ctx;
    includeInventory = inventory;
    new AsyncCheckServerDate().execute();       
}

public static String buildProgress(int value, int max) {
    int percent = (int)(((double)value / (double)max) * 100);
    String current = value + " of " + max + " (" + percent + "% completed)";                    
    return current;
}

public static void createProgress() {
    if (progress == null) {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    }

    if (!progress.isShowing()) {
        progress.show();
    }
}

protected static class AsyncCheckServerDate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String today = "";
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {               
            JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetDateToday();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            today = parser.parseDateToday(jsonObj);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return today;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //progress.show(manager, tag)
        /*progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progress.setMessage("Verifying server date. Please wait...");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progress.show();*/

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals(StaticHolder.today())) {
            new AsyncCustomers().execute();             
        }
        else {
            AppMessages.showMessage(context,
                                    "The date on this device is not synchronized with the server. Please adjust it to the correct date.",
                                    "Date Out of Sync", 
                                    AppMessages.MESSAGE_INFO,
                                    null);          
        }
    }
}

protected static class AsyncCustomers extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Customer> customers = null;
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {               
            JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetReferenceFiles((byte)4);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            customers = parser.parseCustomer(jsonObj);
            CustomersTable.importData(context, customers, this);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        super.onPreExecute();
        createProgress();
        progress.setTitle("Downloading Customer Information");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        new AsyncItems().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {     
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progress.setMessage(values[0]);
    }

    public void showProgress(int value, int max) {          
        publishProgress(buildProgress(value, max));
    }

}

protected static class AsyncItems extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Item> items = null;
        RestAPI api = new RestAPI();
        try {               
            JSONObject jsonObj = api.GetReferenceFiles((byte)6);
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            items = parser.parseItem(jsonObj);
            ItemsTable.importData(context, items, this);                
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        super.onPreExecute();
        createProgress();
        progress.setTitle("Downloading Items Master File");         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (progress != null) {
           progress.dismis();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {     
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progress.setMessage(values[0]);
    }

    public void showProgress(int value, int max) {
        publishProgress(buildProgress(value, max));
    }

}

}
```

CustomerTable class (separate file)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class CustomersTable {

public static void importData(Context context, ArrayList<Customer> customers, ReferenceFilesDownloader.AsyncCustomers async) {
        ADIDBContext dbContext = new ADIDBContext(context);     
        String query = "DELETE FROM Customers";
        dbContext.execSQL(query);   
        try {
            dbContext.beginTransaction();
        int row = 0;
        for (Customer customer : customers) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            async.showProgress(++row, customers.size());

            values.put("CustomerId", customer.customerId);
            values.put("LastName", customer.lastName);
            values.put("FirstName", customer.firstName);

            values.put("MiddleName", customer.middleName);
            values.put("Address1", customer.address1);
            values.put("Address2", customer.address2);              

            values.put("ProvinceId", customer.provinceId);
            values.put("CityId", customer.cityId);
            values.put("BarangayId", customer.barangayId);

            dbContext.getDatabase().insert("Customers", null, values);
        }

        dbContext.setTransactionSuccessful();                       
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {          
    }       
    dbContext.endTransaction();
    dbContext.close();              
}

}
```

ItemTable class (separate file)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ItemsTable {
    public static void importData(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items, ReferenceFilesDownloader.AsyncItems async) {
    ADIDBContext dbContext = new ADIDBContext(context);
    String query = "DELETE FROM Items";
    dbContext.execSQL(query);

    try {
        dbContext.beginTransaction();

        int row = 0;
        for (Item item : items) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            async.showProgress(++row, items.size());

            values.put("Barcode", item.barcode);
            values.put("ItemId", item.itemId);
            values.put("ItemDesc", item.itemDesc);
            values.put("UnitId", item.unitId);

            values.put("CompanyId", item.companyId);
            values.put("UnitDescription", item.unitDescription);
            values.put("UnitConversion", item.unitConversion);

            values.put("Cost", item.cost);

            values.put("SellingPrice1", item.sellingPrice1);
            values.put("SellingPrice2", item.sellingPrice2);
            values.put("SellingPrice3", item.sellingPrice3);
            values.put("SellingPrice4", item.sellingPrice4);
            values.put("SellingPrice5", item.sellingPrice5);

            values.put("PiecePrice1", item.piecePrice1);
            values.put("PiecePrice2", item.piecePrice2);
            values.put("PiecePrice3", item.piecePrice3);
            values.put("PiecePrice4", item.piecePrice4);
            values.put("PiecePrice5", item.piecePrice5);

            values.put("Taxable", item.taxable);

            dbContext.getDatabase().insert("Items", null, values);
        }

        dbContext.setTransactionSuccessful();                       
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {          
    }       
    dbContext.endTransaction();
    dbContext.close();              
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is when the device is rotated or when it goes to sleep,
>   then the ProgressDialog disappears and an exception is raised when I
>   call dismiss() from the final OnPostExecute.

If I'm not wrong you are trying to handle the orientation change that causes the exception.

**SOLUTION 1: Prevent the Activity from being recreated**

Add this attribute into your activity manifest,

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

It hand off to your `onConfigurationChanged()` method and does nothing other than re-measuring the layout. That should solve the problem during rotation.

**SOLUTION 2: Lock the screen orientation**

Define a fixed orientation for your activity and that should solve the issue.

```
<activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   ...  />
```

**SOLUTION 3: Temporarily lock the screen in `onPreExecute()`, and unlock it in `onPostExecute()`**

This is a tricky way to handle orientation. Simply lock the orientation when the AsyncTask is about to start then unlock the orientation when the Task has been finished. See the example,

```
@Override
public void onTaskStarted() {
    lockScreenOrientation();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CopyOfCopyOfMainActivity.this, "Loading", "Please wait a moment!");
}

@Override
public void onTaskFinished(String result) {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    unlockScreenOrientation();
}

private void lockScreenOrientation() {
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}

private void unlockScreenOrientation() {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
}
```